# recursive list processing seems to be changing the list at higher levels

Tags: c#, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to write a competition pairing algorithm to avoid playing the same player twice

so we have a list of players

we take the first player, then the first player they have not played

remove that from the list

send the remaining list to be processed again

if the last pair cant play, the recursion should unroll and the first player get matched against the next player they have not played, and away we go again .

What seems to be happening is that the original list (players) is changing size along with the truncated list that is sent out through the recursive call.

So when the reucrsion unwinds, the list players is down to 2 items rather than the expected 4 or 6.  It is like the list is being passed by reference rather than by value.

any thoughts?

edit***

not so much the list being passed by reference, but the list (players) being changed each time the procedure is called, so we end up with the first iteration of the procedure (which should have a list of 6 players) using a list of 2 players when the recursion unwinds ***

Ive shoved the whole code in here (along with the test list set up code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;

namespace CPair
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create players
            List<int> alist = new List<int>() { 2 };
            var a = new Player(1, "a", "wk", alist, 10);

            List<int> blist = new List<int>() { 1 };
            var b = new Player(2, "b", "wa", blist, 9);

            List<int> clist = new List<int>() {  };
            var c = new Player(3, "c", "bc", clist, 8);

            List<int> dlist = new List<int>() {  };
            var d = new Player(4, "d", "wk", dlist, 7);

            List<int> elist = new List<int>() {  };
            var e = new Player(5, "e", "bc", elist, 5);

            List<int> flist = new List<int>() {  };
            var f = new Player(6, "f", "ab", flist, 3);

            List<Player> PlayList = new List<Player>();
            PlayList.Add(a);
            PlayList.Add(b);
            PlayList.Add(c);
            PlayList.Add(d);
            PlayList.Add(e);
            PlayList.Add(f);

            PlayList.Sort((p, q) => p.Points.CompareTo(q.Points));

            foreach (Player p in PlayList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.PlayerName);
            }

            List<Player> paired = new List<Player>();
            paired = pairing(PlayList);

            foreach (Player r in paired)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.PlayerName);
            }
        }

        static List<Player> pairing(List<Player> players)
        {
            List<Player> pairingList = new List<Player>();
            int n = 1;
            bool failed = true;
            List<Player> returnedList = new List<Player>();

            while ((failed) && n <= players.Count - 1)
            {
                if (PairIsGood(players[0], players[n], 0))
                {
                    Player p1 = new Player();
                    p1 = players[0];
                    Player p2 = new Player();
                    p2 = players[n];

                    if (players.Count <= 2)
                    {
                        returnedList.Add(p1);
                        returnedList.Add(p2);
                        failed = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<Player> nextPairs = new List<Player>();
                        nextPairs = players;
                        nextPairs.RemoveAt(0);
                        nextPairs.RemoveAt(n-1);

                        returnedList = pairing(nextPairs);
                        Console.WriteLine(players.Count.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(nextPairs.Count.ToString());

                        if (returnedList.Count == 0)
                        {
                            failed = true;
                            n++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            returnedList.Add(p1);
                            returnedList.Add(p2);
                            failed = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    n++;
                }
            } 

            return returnedList;
        }

       static bool PairIsGood(Player p1, Player p2, int round)
       {
            bool good = true;

            foreach (int op in p1.OpList)
            {
                if (op == p2.PlayerID)
                {
                    good = false;
                }
            }

            return good;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference in c#

Comment: well, after all that (many hours of faffing)  I feel rather dense

Comment: ...though that doesnt actually seem to be the problem - its not so much the list being passed by reference, but the list (players) being changed each time the procedure is called, so we end up with the first iteration of the procedure (which should have a list of 6 players) using a list of 2 players when the recursion unwinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
List<Player> nextPairs = new List<Player>();
nextPairs = players;
nextPairs.RemoveAt(0);
nextPairs.RemoveAt(n-1);
```

You create a new `List<Player>` and assign it to `nextPairs`

You then effectively throw that new list away, and instead assign `nextPairs` to `players`.

`nextPairs` and `players` are now both referencing the same list, and removing from `nextPairs` will remove from `players` too, since they're the same list.

Take a look at `Array.Copy()` if you want a true independent copy.

As an aside, I see you are doing the same redundant creation pattern here:

```
Player p1 = new Player();
p1 = players[0];
Player p2 = new Player();
p2 = players[n];
```

This should simply be

```
Player p1 = players[0];
Player p2 = players[n];
```

I suspect you need to read up a bit on objects and references and how they work.

Comment: in this case the redundancy came in as I took single lines apart to try and work out what was going wrong.  But you are correct - I did not have a handle on the referencing.  I made assumptions about copying arrays that were just plain wrong.  Thanks for the help..got it sorted now.